# C# Wrapping a primitive

Tags: c#

I known that deriving a class from a primitive is not possible, however, I would like my class to 'seem' like it's a primitive without casting. In this case, my class would operate much like a Decimal:

```
    public interface IFoo
    {
        static explicit operator Decimal(IFoo tFoo);
    }

    public class Foo: IFoo
    {
        private Decimal m_iFooVal;

        public Decimal Value
        {
            get { return m_iFooVal; }
            set { m_iFooVal= value; }
        }

        static explicit operator Decimal(IFoo tFoo)
        {
            return (tFoo as Foo).Value;
        }

    }
```

The above code doesn't work because the explicit operator cannot be defined in an interface. My code deals with interfaces and I would like to keep it like that. Is it possible to convert IFoo to a Decimal? Any alternatives are welcome. Example:

```
IFoo tMyFooInterfaceReference = GetFooSomehow();    
Decimal iVal = tMyFooInterfaceReference;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just add another method to your `IFoo` interface called `ToDecimal()` and call that when needed?

```
public interface IFoo
{
    decimal ToDecimal();
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public decimal Value { get; set; }

    public decimal ToDecimal() { return Value; }
}
```

Your code wouldn't be that much more complicated:

```
IFoo tMyFooInterfaceReference = GetFooSomehow();
decimal iVal = tMyFooInterfaceReference.ToDecimal();
```

Comment: This is the correct approach. The interface defines a contract, the class implements the contract, and the rest of the world *knows what that contract is*, unlike with a hypothetical conversion.